# Connect to Mysql server to run tasks on two databases

Tags: mysql

I am writing a script to perform tasks between two MySql databases on the same server, i.e truncate tables on one db and import table rows from another db to this one.

The user who is doing the tasks has full permissions on both databases.

How do I connect to both databases from the command line?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: hey, if you found either of our answers helpful, don't forget to mark the question as answered by giving one of us the "tick." Personally, I'd appreciate if you gave me the tick, I could do with the rep, and I'd get a badge for first answer awarded :) but it's up to you :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mysql`command line utility with the proper parameters:

```
mysql -u root -h your_host -p your_db
```

Here `root` is the privileged user and `your_db` is the database which is in use by default. You can always switch between databases by typing `use another_db` command from `mysql`console.

Also note that you do not have to select dabase (`use db_name`) in order to execute query on it. You can for example write a query something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, b.title FROM db1.table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN db2.table AS b ON b.id = a.foreign_id
```

Comment: Thanks Emre, that cleared it up for me. I assumed that if I was running tasks on 2 different databases I would have to connect to both of them rather than just one.

Comment: @Paul You are actually connecting to database server which is listening to a socket (TCP or UNIX), not the database's itself. So you do not need different connections for different databases on the same database server.

Answer (score 3):

erm, well I would suggest you open up two terminal windows. the command to connect is:

mysql -u DBUSERNAME -h DBSERVER -p DBNAME

assuming you have mysql installed, which for ubuntu would be: sudo apt-get install mysql

Comment: http://blog.eukhost.com/webhosting/how-to-connect-to-my-mysql-database/ this is useful for more reading